# verify a login with android when password is crypted BCRYPT

Tags: php, android, web-services, symfony, bcrypt

so i had my table user (with crypted password) and am using it fine with symfony

security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt
```

and trying to connect my android application in the some DB, but it's not possible cause the password are crypted, i even tryed to add new Libary under php/lib/password.php to use "password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)"

i hope find a solution together guys, i am really upset about that.

this is my "login.php" under htdocs to connect my android app to the DB

```
<?php

    define('HOST','localhost');
    define('USER','root');
    define('PASS','');
    define('DB','swib');

    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $password2 = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $sql = "select * from swib_user where username='$username' and password='$password2'";

    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);



    $check = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

    if (isset($check)) {
      echo 'success';
    } else {
      echo 'failure';
    }

    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

ps: that's work's fine with another DB (i mean with normal password, not crypted)

Comment: You should check the manual, a new hash will be different every time because of the changing salt. You need `password_verify`.

Comment: thank you @jeroen i try your solution, but it still not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// if this is under web folder
// adjust it according where this script is located
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\BCryptPasswordEncoder;

$encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder(16); // initialize with some int between 4 and 31

define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('USER', 'root');
define('PASS', '');
define('DB', 'database');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']); // don't forget about security
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "select password, salt from swib_user where username='$username'"; // if you do not have salt in your table, remove it from select and leave only password

$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$check = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

// if you do not have salt in your table, you should use returning value of $user->getSalt() method for this user. or null if you don't use salt
if (isset($check) && $encoder->isPasswordValid($check['password'], $password, $check['salt'])) {
    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'failure';
}

mysqli_close($con);
```